# Cannot correct JSplumb drag offset

Tags: jsplumb

Okay random question:

Can anyone hazard a guess as to why my mouse cursor would be so wildly offset from the new endpoint I've created in JSPlumb? I've checked the canvas is relative the div is absolute and tinkered with all sorts but I can't shift the offset.

[image: JSPlumb screenshot]

Comment: are you using an image for the end-point ? If yes, then what is the size of image ?

Comment: sorry for the delay, got side tracked. There's not images involved its the same for every type of end point as well.

Comment: please create a fiddle, demonstrating the issue.